# For a matrix, how many continuous submatrices exist?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

This question came from trying to understand Kadane's Algorithm on 2D arrays. I was following [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-27-max-sum-rectangle-in-a-2d-matrix/) solution on geeksforgeeks but I realized I am just not able to visualize how many submatrices will exist.

Comment: If you know the answer to your question, you can add it as an answer here so that other people will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've found an answer, it is explained really well in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCQN096CwWM&feature=youtu.be). I understood both the number of submatrices and the dynamic programming solution that implements Kadane's method to find the submatrix with the largest sum.